# What do Monero addresses have in common?

Tags: address-verification

Monero addresses are very long and are supposed to be random, but I have noticed that all of them start with the number 4. Are there any other similarities shared by all Monero addresses?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to http://monero.wikia.com/wiki/Address_validation:

> Monero addresses may seem random, but they have the following details in common:
>
> - They consist of 95 characters
> - They start with a 4
> - The second character can only be a number (0-9), or letters A or B

Comment: Note that subaddresses begin with the character '8'. This wasn't a thing back when this question was asked and answered, but for the benefit of people stumbling on this from a Google search: a valid XMR address can begin with either '4' or '8'.

Answer (score 14):

A more technical answer on how addresses are generated is provided below, as found [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html). Any similarities between the addresses are a consequence of how they're created.
As you can see, the first byte is always the same which, when encoded to base58, results in addresses starting with "4".

> To create the actual Public Address, the following is performed:
>
> 1. The pair of public keys are prepended with one network byte (the number 18, 0x12, for Monero). It looks like this: (network byte) +
>      (32-byte public spend key) + (32-byte public view key).
> 2. These 65 bytes are hashed with Keccak-256.
> 3. The first four bytes of the hash from 2. are appended to 1., creating a 69-byte Public Address.
> 4. As a last step, this 69-byte string is converted to Base58. However, it's not done all at once like a Bitcoin address, but rather
>      in 8-byte blocks. This gives us eight full-sized blocks and one 5-byte
>      block. Eight bytes converts to 11 or less Base58 characters; if a
>      particular block converts to <11 characters, the conversion pads it
>      with "1"s (1 is 0 in Base58). Likewise, the final 5-byte block can
>      convert to 7 or less Base58 digits; the conversion will ensure the
>      result is 7 digits. Due to the conditional padding, the 69-byte string
>      will always convert to 95 Base58 characters (8 * 11 + 7).
> 5. This 95-character result is the (obscenely long) Cryptonote Public Address!
> 6. If you're creating an integrated address, simply append the 64-bit payment ID to step 1 and continue; everything else is the same except
>      for the lengths (77 bytes total, 106 Base58 digits) and the prepended
>      byte (19, 0x13).

Comment: Thank you. For someone who make a very simple validate API... Integrated address is 106 characters. So it should be
"They consist of 95 or 106 characters." Also the second character of integrated address can be a character. "The second character can only be a number (0-9), or letters A or B" is not right.