# How can I check if a Monero address is valid?

Tags: address-verification

Handling a user's input in which I want to make sure that he used a valid monero address.

Bitcoin has all these rules found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127317/check-if-bitcoin-address-is-valid) and I found something [similar](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid) for ethereum as well.

I was wondering if Monero has some general rules I can be checking the user's input to check the address' validity.

Comment: [i check github project, found this link](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5141/commits/5c81a9f1a113e6932b019ba9f0d72b9ccd7cf743)

Comment: This would be a good answer if you did not just post a link. Please consider writing a quick overview and I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you will find an answer [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/what-do-monero-addresses-have-in-common), although the question was asked in a different way.

Practically, you'd verify the network byte, length, address encoding and checksum. For implementation details, I suppose you could inspect source of [this page](https://xmr.llcoins.net/) (javascript), or go to the monero [github](https://github.com/monero-project) repo.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function verify_checksum($address)
    {
        $decoded = $this->base58->decode($address);
        $checksum = substr($decoded, -8);
        $test = substr($decoded, 0, 130);
        $checksum_hash = $this->keccak_256(substr($decoded, 0, 130));
        $calculated = substr($checksum_hash, 0, 8);
        if($checksum == $calculated){
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
```