# How to perform a simple verification of a Monero address with a regular expression?

Tags: address-verification, javascript, regular-expression

For people that want to do a simple verification of a Monero address to ensure it has been entered correctly, what are some methods that can be employed?

Comment: Related question: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/what-do-monero-addresses-have-in-common

Comment: Full verification requires complex checks: See the `addrCheck()` function here: https://xmr.llcoins.net/js/site.js

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple regular expression and javascript code snippet that can be used to confirm a Monero address has been entered correctly.

Regular expression:

`4[0-9AB][<insert-all-base-58-characters-here>]{93}`

In Javascript:

```
addr_str.match(/4[0-9AB][123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]{93}/);
```

Credit goes to [/u/binaryfate](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/52jvr3/regular_expression_for_validating_a_monero_address/d7kuboc) for the useful info.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this doesn't ensure that there are no typos (can't really check checksum with regular expressions), and that it's suitable only for regular addresses

Comment: To ferretinjapan, you might want to look at the code for steps 8 to 15 [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html). Might be beneficial to this question or for a new question.

Comment: If you go on https://moneroaddress.org and type in both `41a` and `41z`, you'll notice it says "INVALID PREFIX" for `41a` (but not for `41z`), while the `a` character is part of [Base58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58). Therefore, I think the regular expression posted is still a simplification.

Comment: @dpzz According to JS code, `lowest_address` = 
"41d7FXjswpK1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112KhNi4" and `highest_address` = 
"4BKnGLZNZ5pjpXCZedGfVQjpXCZedGfVQjpXCZedGfVQjpXCZedGfVQjpXCZedGfVQjpXCZedGfVQjpXCZedGfVQVmzCh57"  I have no idea if that is technically correct.

Comment: Should have a `^` at the front since the address must start with a `4` i.e. `.match(/^4...`

Comment: @dpzz – That site is incorrect. Lowercase `z` is indeed one of the constituent characters of base58. [Monero's base58 implementation](https://monerodocs.org/cryptography/base58/) clearly says it's base64 minus `IO10+/`, just like Bitcoin's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is better:

```
4[a-zA-Z|\d]{94}
```

And payment ID:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]{64}
```

Comment: This does not check for base58 instead of base64.

Comment: The Payment ID is supposed to be hex, but can be 16 or 64 chars.  The address regex is very loose and includes invalid characters plus a nonsense pipe character.  Better see the selected answer as this one has big problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are some inappropriate regexes to the other answers here. At this time, only [ferretinjapan's answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1602/9542) is correct, though it's a mouthful since it does not use ranges.

This regex will match (non-integrated) Monero addresses ([subaddresses](https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/) start with `8`):

```
^[48][0-9AB][1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{93}$
```

An [integrated address](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3179/9542) has [106 or 136 characters](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2061/9542) and that the second character may be any base58 character (verification needed; this is a result of changing the netbyte prefix). Here's a regex to match *just* integrated (either 64-bit or full 256-bit) addresses:

```
^4[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{105}(?:[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{30})?$
```

To match any Monero address (standard, subaddress, integrated, or full 256-bit integrated):

```
^(?:[48][0-9AB]|4[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{12}(?:[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{30})?)[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{93}$
```

With any of these regexes, if you are extracting addresses from larger bodies of text, you likely want to replace the `^` and `$` anchors with `\b` word boundary markers.

Comment: Can you update to include subaddresses please?

Comment: @sgp – Yes, done.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago someone pointed to me this regex to address

```
/4([0-9]|[A-B])(.){93}/
```

I belive its an more complete one, I am using it on PHP-Monero

Comment: This is not an accurate regex.  The `.` (dot) matches any character.

Answer (score 0):

My Java Example:

```
public static boolean MoneroValid(String addr)
{
    String regex = "^4[0-9AB][1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{93}$";
    return addr.matches(regex);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't catch integrated addresses, stagenet or testnet addresses.