# Open alias integrated address

Tags: payment-id, integrated-address, openalias

Open Alias addresses are great. Integrated addresses are great. But is it possible to add a payment ID to an Open Alias address? eg:

donate@getmonero.com#057980027d4b36df

Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, though I don't think a wallet implementation of it exists at the moment.

First, we need to understand that OpenAlias is simply a protocol whereby a DNS lookup can be used to query an alias, such as donate@getmonero.org, and return a regular address. As of 21 March 2017 for this example, this is:

`44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A`

Understanding the construction of an address and of an integrated address is also crucial, and is discussed here: [What is an integrated address?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address)
Given that we understand how to construct both a normal address and an integrated address, a rundown of how a wallet could send to an integrated address using an OpenAlias name is as follows:

**Given:** `donate@getmonero.com#057980027d4b36df`

1. Parse:

   - OpenAlias: donate@getmonero.com
   - Payment ID: `057980027d4b36df`
2. Get address via OpenAlias:
   `44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A`
3. Decode address:

   - Version (hex): `12`
   - Public Spend Key: `42f18fc61586554095b0799b5c4b6f00cdeb26a93b20540d366932c6001617b7`
   - Public View Key: `5db35109fbba7d5f275fef4b9c49e0cc1c84b219ec6ff652fda54f89f7f63c88`
4. Encode integrated address:

   - Version (hex): `13` <-- Note that integrated addresses use a difference version #
   - Public Spend Key: `42f18fc61586554095b0799b5c4b6f00cdeb26a93b20540d366932c6001617b7`
   - Public View Key: `5db35109fbba7d5f275fef4b9c49e0cc1c84b219ec6ff652fda54f89f7f63c88`
   - Payment ID: `057980027d4b36df`

**Output Integrated Address:** `4DrvGduF3ynBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVPkaWoLSK6nHSCXS5b6`

So a company could easily say "please pay 4 XMR to `pay@mystore.com#0123456789abcdef`". The important thing in terms of making this useful is that the payment ID does not need to be included in the OpenAlias registration, which would be an unsustainable solution.