# Where to find my XMR Wallet Address?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Sorry for the simple question, I am new to Monero and wondering where I find my Wallet address. In the Monero Wallet GUI I see an reception adress in the first line. Is this my unique address? And what means the integrated address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the Monero Wallet GUI I see an reception address in the first line. Is this my unique address?

Correct. This is your unique "plain" address. Note that you can also find your plain address in `<wallet-name>.address.txt`, which is stored in the directory of your wallet files (`Documents\Monero` for Windows | `~/Monero` for Mac OS X and Linux).

> And what means the integrated address?

An integrated address is a plain address with the short, encrypted payment ID embedded. Merchants and services (e.g. exchanges) give each user a unique integrated address, such that they are able to distinguish between incoming transactions (in case of exchanges) or payments (in case of merchants). Note that plain addresses are 95 characters, whereas integrated addresses are 106 characters. More information about integrated addresses can be found here:

[What is an integrated address?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address)

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrated-address