# Why are there many Monero addresses starting with 4JUdGzv...QvVCjZb?

Tags: address

So far I've found:

- **4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZb**Rx8NCvspxJMRJcG69H
- **4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZb**RyrP3MvTGHZ5ASzpW8
- **4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZb**RydwE9i8Yg26PQWw8e
- **4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZb**S31oxhFoqyC1zg7KGP

These come from:

- my XMR deposit address at Poloniex
- the donation address at www.monero.how
- a random post at forum.bits.media
- a random post at YouTube

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're all Poloniex's deposit address. The bit at the end is the payment ID used to identify the depositor's Poloniex account. You can read more about integrated addresses here: [What is an integrated address?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address)