# What is the XMR Withdrawal field for when there is another address field on top for Binance?

Tags: address, exchange, binance

On the binance withdraw website, there is an xmr address field and then below it there is another `xmr withdrawal` field. What is that field for?

[image: XMR Withdrawal Address]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really is kind of misleading at Binance and i think they do it on purpose.

The field `XMR Withdrawal Address` is the wallet. The field `XMR Withdrawal` is the payment ID.

If you want to transfer XMR to your own wallet, you don't need to enter anything into the `XMR Withdrawal` field aka payment ID. But if you want to transfer XMR to a wallet at an exchange, then you often need to add a payment ID that you get together with your wallet address from the exchange you want to transfer XMR to.

Now the interesting part: If you don't get a payment ID along with the wallet address from an exchange, then most of the time you got an integrated wallet. An integrated wallet is a wallet that already includes the payment ID inside of the wallet address string.

So if you don't get any payment ID, don't worry, just enter the integrated wallet address into field `XMR Withdrawal Address`, check the `No` checkbox to indicate that you don't want to add a separate payment ID and hit the button!

I had the same problem while transferring XMR from Binance to Kraken. Worked flawlessly the way i described it.

If you want to know more about integrated wallet addresses, take a look [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address)

Answer (score 1):

It could be for payment_id try inspecting it in source to see if that reveals any more info.