# Monero address generated by Kraken

Tags: address

I have a Kraken account and got a Monero address, generated by them.

It starts with `4GdoN7NCTi8a5gZu` and has 106 characters in total. There are digits, letters from A to Z, low case and capitals. There are no special symbols in it.

I'm trying to input this address in monerospelunker, but it does not recognize it as valid. The program recognizes other addresses (that are not mine, just found on the web) as valid.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it Kraken? Or does the program expect something else?

Comment: Kraken generates a wallet address with integrated payment id. That kind of wallet is called "integrated wallet". In general you can send coins to a wallet and optionally enter a payment id. At Kraken you get that combined directly in the wallet address. Maybe monerospelunker can't handle integrated addresses?

Answer (score 1):

As @Endogen mentioned in the comments, this is an integrated address. Integrated addresses are no longer supported by any Monero software, so you shouldn't have this issue going forwards with Kraken addresses.

You can see the technical explanation of integrated addresses here: [What is an integrated address?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address)