# How to generate integrated addresses without a node?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, integrated-address

I am working on a Monero invoice solution for a client, and I would like to use integrated addresses to allow the client to reconcile payments. It's cost prohibitive to run a private node just to generate these addresses. Is there a JS library for generating an integrated address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by el00ruobuob, subaddresses are the way to go.

However, you can manually build integrated addresses as per this detailed answer: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3184/7493

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a node to generate an integrated address.
You only need the monero-wallet-rpc and call the [appropriate method](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address).

Edit: but you should also look at the [subaddresses](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_address) which are designed for the same purpose and will be available for a longer time.

Btw, how do you expect to confirm payment without a node?
A remote node does not seems trustworthy for such use case.

Comment: Thank you. That helps, but still requires the client to carry an additional cost to host the service. For context, the client manually confirms payment with their wallet.

Comment: In such context I would suggest to manually generate a subaddress per payment with their wallet.

Comment: Step 1: User orders item on website. Step 2: User pays invoice. Step 3: Client checks wallet at EOD and marks invoices as paid. Not the best system, I agree, but they aren't willing to make investment to automate.

Comment: You could run a wallet-rpc on the website host, and query it to generate a subaddress?