# Generate an integrated address from a different wallet's standard address

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I am attempting to generate an integrated address from a standard address, via an RPC call to a `monero-wallet-rpc` instance with an unrelated wallet. It seems I always get back an integrated address from the default address in the loaded wallet.

Is is possible to generate an integrated address for a standard address that is totally unrelated to the loaded wallet?

I am running

`{"jsonrpc": "2.0","i": "0","method": "make_integrated_address","params": {"standard_address":"55LTR8KniP4LQGJSPtbYDacR7dz8RBFnsfAKMaMuwUNYX6aQbBcovzDPyrQF9KXF9tVU6Xk3K8no1BywnJX6GvZX8yJsXvt", "payment_id": "5626bb63c38aec3c"}}`

which returns

`4DKZNCZKW2MguWaxD3AnycfqJAdRMMy17iyAVunUBKVNAKgn41PZrNkSWQybGjkpXvfL553pN5aMdWn5Bq1DkupXi1bt4GJou4g3an4XCz`

and then

`{"jsonrpc": "2.0","i": "0","method": "split_integrated_address","params": {"integrated_address": "4DKZNCZKW2MguWaxD3AnycfqJAdRMMy17iyAVunUBKVNAKgn41PZrNkSWQybGjkpXvfL553pN5aMdWn5Bq1DkupXi1bt4GJou4g3an4XCz"}}`

which returns

`43ctMPjptkqguWaxD3AnycfqJAdRMMy17iyAVunUBKVNAKgn41PZrNkSWQybGjkpXvfL553pN5aMdWn5Bq1DkupXUfpSmcn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a version issue. Older versions of Monero did not take the standard_address argument, will ignore it, and generate an address using the loaded wallet.

Fixed the "issue" by upgrading to 0.13.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The only way, via RPC, is to load a wallet with `monero-wallet-rpc` and call the [make_integrated_address](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address) method. This accepts either no address or a supplied address, and a payment ID.

However, depending on your use-case and with a little code, it is fairly simple to create an integrated address from a given standard address and payment ID. The format is described in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3184/7493).

Comment: Ok thank you. In that case, what is the "standard_address" argument for?

Comment: Yes I just corrected the answer, you can indeed pass in a standard address too. In any case, you still have to load a wallet to be able to call this method.

Comment: Ok, so I have loaded a wallet, but I am supplying an argument of a standard address from a different wallet. It always returns an integrated address that relates back to the loaded wallet. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: No. If you are supplying a standard address as one of the parameters, the returned integrated address will be for the supplied address, not the address of the loaded wallet. Suggest you double check because I just checked the code and ran a test and works as expected.

Comment: I edited my question to include my code that is malfunctioning.

Comment: Your input address looks off. It should start with a 4.

Comment: Turned out to be a version issue... Thank you for your help.