# How can I set a payment ID of 64 characters hex on wallet cli?

Tags: payment-id, integrated-address

I´ve been asked to send a 64 digit payment ID. I used the command:

> integrated_address

but it shows only the 16 digit payment ID. Thanks! :)

Comment: Typically, if you're asked for a payment id when sending to your own wallet, it's optional. If it's you sending to another wallet, the payment id to use will be given to you by the recipient. In this case, it looks like the former, so you should be able to leave it blank after you confirm this is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Payment ID is really a message attached to the TX. Usually it's only important when sending to exchanges, services etc. because they use just one address for receiving funds from different users and PID is the only way they can tell them apart.

### Sending

If you're *sending* to an [**integrated address**](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address) then just use: `transfer [address] [amount]`. You can recognize it's an integrated address because it's longer (106 characters vs 95 in regular)

If you're *sending* to a [**regular address**](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/what-do-monero-addresses-have-in-common) + [payment ID](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/paymentid), then be sure to use: `transfer [address] [amount] [paymentID]`. Don't forget the payment ID in this case!

### Receiving

If you want to *receive* something with the PID attached, use `integrated_address` and give it to your sender. It will generate a random 16-digit PID and encode it together with your regular address into the integrated format. Then, you'll be able to tell apart incoming payments by using `payments [PID]` command to filter according to payment ID.

To *receive* something with 256-bit PID, just generate random 64 hexadecimal "digits" by any means you like! Then give both your regular address and the payment ID to the sender, and he must be sure not to forget to attach it in the command when sending. That's why integrated format is more convenient.