# Do not come coins to the GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id

when transferring from the exchange, I created in my wallet a "payment id" in an arbitrary format, namely "qwertyuiopasdfgh", I indicated the exact amount of the receipt. After that, the address I specified when translating on the exchange was generated(integrated address). It has been more than a day, and the coins have not been credited to my wallet. Have I done everything right? and how do I get or refund the funds? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending Monero to yourself from an exchange a payment ID or integrated address is [generally unnecessary](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-is-a-payment-id-and-why-is-it-used) because you know when and where the Monero came from and in what amount.

Based on "paid" in your screenshot it appears as if the transaction was sent. With the transaction ID / hash provided by the exchange you will be able to follow [these steps](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived) to verify you received the Monero.

If the Monero was sent, you will be able to see your Monero in your wallet after your GUI has synced or [connecting to a remote node](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain).

Comment: " see your Monero in your wallet after your GUI has synced". Phew!!! Got me stressing for a minute :)