# Can i receive payment from bittrex without payment id?

Tags: payment-id, bittrex

I created offline paper wallet from moneroaddress.org and i gave me no payment ID.

[image: Bittrex xmr withdraw page] asks for payment ID.Can i receive my funds from Bittrex just using my public address without payment ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a payment ID when you're sending *to* your **own** wallet. Thus, simply put your wallet's address in the `Base Address` box, specify a `Quantity`, and leave the `Payment_ID` box blank. More information about use cases of the payment ID:

[What is a payment ID, and why is it used?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-is-a-payment-id-and-why-is-it-used)

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-id

P.S. If you want to verify that your transaction correctly arrived, use this guide:

[How do I, as a recipient, verify that my transaction actually arrived?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived)