# Correct Monero address but wrong payment id - MyMonero wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mymonero, exchange

I used changelly to exchange ETH to XMR. While exchanging I entered correct payment address and payment id shown in the mymonero wallet. I closed the mymonero wallet and when reopened it was another payment id now. The exchange already took place with the old paymentid. I have not yet received the payment in my wallet. Can someone please help me

https://xmrchain.net/tx/e2f6ae564acbe10c3d94c659dbe48debb91005e516e3a321c83e0064345e6be3

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a payment ID when you're sending *to* your **own** wallet. Thus, simply use your wallet's address and nothing else. More information about use cases of the payment ID:

[What is a payment ID, and why is it used?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-is-a-payment-id-and-why-is-it-used)

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-id

P.S. If you want to verify that your transaction correctly arrived, use this guide:

[How do I, as a recipient, verify that my transaction actually arrived?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived)