# When sending monero with a payment id, is the transaction still 100% anounymous?

Tags: privacy, payment-id

Are monero transactions still anonymous when using a payment ID? For example, I send to coins to a address with a payment ID. Is this transaction still 100% anonymous impossible to track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using a payment Id still maintains Monero’s privacy features

A payment Id allows **the receiver** to keep track of incoming payments from specific sources.

The best way to use a payment is to integrate it directly into a wallet address by creating an **integrated address**. This will generate a unique address with an integrated payment Id that **the receiver** can give to a specific source so **the receiver** can keep track of a payment from that source.

See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-is-a-payment-id-and-why-is-it-used/4339) and [here](https://getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/paymentid.html) for more details

Note: when transferring monero to your wallet from some exchanges, they will ask you for a payment id in a separate field to the address, in this case you should use your original address (not the integrated address) and the payment id separately