# Help I forgot to enter a payment ID help

Tags: payment-id

Iam using monero gui, but I don t have a payment id. What can I do ? Please help me ? They have send my the monero but I have forgetten to enter a paymend ID. My monero know lost ?

Comment: Are you asking about moneros sent by someone else to you, or about moneros sent by you to someone else?

Comment: @achmed alyari: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using wallet/exchange service from a company like poloniex? 
If so, you need to contact them about your transaction

As I know...
If you use your own wallet, you don't need to worry about payment id.

Comment: Here is payment id info. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-is-a-payment-id-and-why-is-it-used/4339

Comment: I have bought it at litebit.eu its not a echange. Iam using monero gui.

Comment: sorry I mean annycoins.

Comment: OK. You bought XMR in annycoins. Then you sent it your monero address. Right??  Question: Are you running monero gui wallet in your computer?? If so, you don't need payment ID. -- Anyway, you need tx hash(transaction id). 1. Get tx hash from annycoins. 2. put your tx hash in https://moneroexplorer.com/ .. If it is confirmed, it sent to your XMR Gui address.